# how to prevent other modules from calling my extern function in c

Tags: c, architecture, module, layer, extern

suppose my program consists of several layers, say, **Layer A** and **Layer B**. The file **a_foo.c** contains my function definitions, the file **a_foo.h** contains function declarations corresponding to definitions in **a_foo.c**.

my design is that modules in the same layer(**layer A** in this case) can invoke functions declared in **a_foo.h** while **Layer B** can not invoke though with **a_foo.h** included.

so how can i achieve that ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate your two layers into two convenience libraries residing in different directories, with only the public header files of each layer in a common include directory.
Thereby, you'll avoid accidental inclusion of a_foo.h in layer B.

If you need stronger access control, you'll need system-dependent hackery. However, this is very unnecessary in most contexts.

Comment: if i dont misunderstand,according to your procedures, if a_foo.h is included in layer B and any one of declared functions in a_foo.h was invoked, the linker of layer B will complain undefined reference to XXX. Am i right ?

Comment: @Tracy: No, but you'd have to include a_foo.h as "../layer_A/a_foo.h" in layer B - which tells you immediately that you are doing something wrong. When you have -Icommon_includes in the compiler flags, public headers of A are included as "a_bar.h" and module-private headers have to be included as "../layer_A/a_foo.h", which makes their privacy obvious to the code-writer. The linker won't even be bothered.

Comment: what if i add -lpath_to_layer_A flags when compiling layer B,which works around to the explicit path inclusion? @thiton

Comment: @Tracy: Then you have just broken the encapsulation. This approach is no form of security, just an encapsulation strategy to avoid accidental use of the other layer. But you don't *need* any security here, this pattern is just there to guard you against oversights.

Comment: that might be a solution though not very thorough. Thank you very much  @thiton

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you'll have a few (preferably *only* a few) functions in any given layer that can/will communicate with other layers. Most of the others are used only inside of that layer.

The tool C provides to do that is `static` -- the few functions that are supposed to be visible to the outside world (so to speak) are `extern`, and prototyped in the header. The rest are `static`. That means their names are only visible within that TU, so nobody else can call them or even see them at all.

```
// a_foo.c
static void internal_function1(whatever_args) { }

static void internal_function2(whatever_args) { }

void external_function1(args) {  /* this code can use internal_function* */ }

// f_foo.h
void external_function1(args);
```

As far as anything outside a_foo.c cares, the names `internal_function1` and `internal_function2` don't exist at all. They're completely invisible. Even if we included prototypes for them in a_foo.h, outside code still wouldn't be able to call them or see them at all.

This, however, is about the only tool that C provides. For what it is, it works pretty well, *but* if the A layer code is large enough that you want to distribute it across a number of source files, things get sticky in a hurry -- C only provides two levels of visibility: either one source file, or all source files. There's no intermediate level of saying it should be visible in source files A, B, and C, but not D, E, or F.